# Is pulumi helm release using helm install or helm upgrade?

Tags: kubernetes-helm, pulumi, helm3

I am trying to use the new Pulumi helm `release` (https://www.pulumi.com/registry/packages/kubernetes/api-docs/helm/v3/release/) and now wondering what helm command is wrapped inside here? Is it using `helm install` underneath or `helm upgrade --install`?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To start with, Helm release resource embeds Helm as a library in the provider.

As for your question, it depends on the state of the release. If it is a fresh install, it should behave similar to a `helm install`. If the resource is seen to be updating, it triggers the equivalent of `helm upgrade`.

Comment: Thanks. Then it is exactly what `helm upgrade --install` does. Do you have any source on your statement?